# Pass codeigniter translation array to jQuery Function

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I’ve a problem by passing an array to a jQuery function. Some code:

```
// in the language file
$lang['daynames'] = array('So','Mo','Di','Mi','Do','Fr','Sa');

//In the view
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var config     = { basePath : '<?php echo $base; ?>' }; // THIS WORKS GREAT!!!
    var days       = new array('<?php echo implode("','",$this->lang->line('daynames')); ?>');
</script>

//in the js-File
    $(function() {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                dateFormat  : 'dd.mm.yy',
                showWeek    : true,
                firstDay    : 1,
                weekHeader  : 'KW',
                dayNamesMin : days,
                monthNames  : ['Januar','Februar','März','April',
                               'Mai','Juni','Juli','August','September',
                               'Oktober','November','Dezember'],
                onSelect    : function(dateText,inst){
                              }
            });
});
```

If I do lang->line(‘daynames’)); ?> in the view everything looks fine, so what is wrong here?

Thanks and best regards ...

Comment: Have you checked the output to see if it looks valid?

Comment: I don't knwow why, Firebug says:
array is not defined
[Break on this error] var days = new array('So','Mo','Di','Mi','Do','Fr','Sa');

Comment: Use object literals where possible. Instead of `new Array()` use `[]`

Answer (score 2):

For a start

```
new array
```

Should be

```
new Array
```

(uppercase A)

Comment: My bad.. didn't see the comments on the question!